# Append Json Array with Calculated Lat and Long

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am receiving a JSON array of locations for restaurants. I want to calculate the distance from the user and to only show the locations closest to my user.I have pulled the data into a function and calculated the latitude and longitude and I have the user's lat and long saved in a variable called distance but, I'm not sure how to:

- Append the lat/long to each item in the array with the venue info
- Calculate the distance from the user
- Print out all venues that show up in that radius.

This is my function:

```
func loadRestaurantss() {
    Helpers.showActivityIndicator(activityIndicator, view)

    APIManager.shared.getRestaurantss { (json) in
        if json != nil {
            self.restaurants = []
            self.filterArray = []
            //Adds all items into the array list dist then goes through them all.
            if let listDis = json["restaurant"].array {
                for item in listDis {
                    let address = item["street_address"].string! + ", " + item["city"].string! + ", " + item["state"].string!

                    self.getLocation(address, { (dis) in
                        self.disLocation = dis
                        self.venueLatt = (self.disLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!
                        self.venueLonn = (self.disLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!
                    })

                    if let snapValue = item.array,
                        let venueLat = self.venueLatt as? Double,
                        let venueLong = self.venueLonn as? Double {
                    }

                    let restaurant = Restaurant(json: item)
                    self.restaurants.append(restaurant)
                }
                print("Dis Test: ", self.restaurants)

                self.tbvRestaurants.reloadData()
                Helpers.hideActivityIndicator(self.activityIndicator)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Variable Calculating both user and venue distance:

```
 let distance = self.calculateDistance(userlat: self.userLatt, userLon: self.userLonn, venueLat: venueLat, venueLon: venueLong)
```

Output from the item array:

```
Item: {
  "state" : "Arizona",
  "city" : "Phoenix",
  "id" : 2,
  "restaurant_name" : "Restaruant  2",
  "street_address" : "123 Fake Street",
  "zip_Code" : 89801,
  "phone" : "123-456-1234",
  "logo" : "http:\/\/foodonthego-.herokuapp.com\/media\/Restaurant_logo\/Phoenix-location_DWt73h5.jpg"
}
```

From here I have the values for the Lat and long stored in VenueLatt/Long respectively. I need to add them to the array. That is what SnapValue is doing but, I realized that the array was not appending and always failing. I've looked around but, can't find a solution.

Comment: I'd breakpoint to make sure you're making it into the `if-let`. If you are making it into the `if-let`, I'd make sure your `Restaurant` constructor is not returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the distance you can use the core location api.

simple example:

```
import CoreLocation

// user location
var userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 59.244696, longitude: 17.813868)

// venue location
var venueLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 59.326354, longitude: 18.072310)

// measure the distance (in km)
var distance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(venueLocation) / 1000
```

Comment: How would I add that to an array with the locations?

Comment: I don't know the type `Restaurant`. But I would recommend you to add an member variable to it, so you can store the distance to the user. With the snippet you provided I can't see how the data in `Restaurant` is stored.